# Implementation of below equation in jupyter or gee

Tags: google-earth-engine, elevation, google-earth-engine-python-api, index

Explanation for the equation: where A is the azimuth of the search direction, (xi , yi )are the coordinates of the cell of interest, and (xy , yy )are the set of all cell coordinates located along the search- vector defined by (xi , yi ), A, and dmax.

Can you look into it and suggest your feedback?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio

#  DEM GeoTIFF file
with rasterio.open('dem.tif') as dem:
    # Read the DEM data 
    dem_data = dem.read(1)  
# Define parameters
dmax = 100  # Maximum search distance 
A = 315  # Azimuth angle in degrees 
# Function to calculate Sx for a given cell
def calculate_sx(Xi, Yi, A, dmax, dem_data):
    sx_values = []
    for distance in range(dmax):
        Xv = Xi + distance * math.cos(math.radians(A))
        Yv = Yi + distance * math.sin(math.radians(A))
        
        if Xv < 0 or Xv >= dem_data.shape[0] or Yv < 0 or Yv >= dem_data.shape[1]:
            break  #  outside the DEM boundaries
        
        elev_diff = dem_data[int(Xv), int(Yv)] - dem_data[Xi, Yi]
        distance_sq = (Xv - Xi) ** 2 + (Yv - Yi) ** 2
        
        # avoid division by zero
        if distance_sq == 0:
            sx_value = 0
        else:
            sx_value = abs(math.tan(elev_diff / distance_sq) ** 0.5)
        
        sx_values.append(sx_value)

    return sum(sx_values) / len(sx_values) if sx_values else 0  # Calculate the mean

# Calculation of mean Sx value
mean_sx_values = np.zeros_like(dem_data, dtype=float)
for xi in range(dem_data.shape[0]):
    for yi in range(dem_data.shape[1]):
        mean_sx_values[xi, yi] = calculate_sx(xi, yi, A, dmax, dem_data)

# visualization 
plt.imshow(mean_sx_values, cmap='terrain')
plt.colorbar(label='Mean Sx Value')
plt.title('Mean Sx Value for the Entire DEM')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code takes a lot of time to run and does not work in GEE

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Code reviews are are offered by [codereview.se]. GIS SE is a problem-solving site. We expect you to explain the problem you are encountering, in the body of the Question. Comments are ephemeral and not really designed to be used by the OP (just [Edit] the Question instead). It seems that "takes a lot of time to run and does not work" does not prioritize the issues appropriately. Of course, "does not work" gives us no idea of where the problem could be located. Please add some debug `print` statements and give us a chance.